# C# - Finding difference between two lists of Process type

Tags: c#, list, process

I am trying to compare the two process lists and get only the difference (the newly started processes).
So when I click a button in my winform, the program should load the oldProcesses, then load the newProcesses, compare them in  Difference and show Difference list. The Difference list on the first time should be empty because oldProcesses and newProcesses are same.
But it does not happen, the problem is with this code: var Difference = newProcesses.Except(oldProcesses).ToList();
How can I get the difference between newProcesses and oldProcesses?
Thank you

```
    Process[] oldProcesses = { };
    int clicked = 0;

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        if (clicked == 0)
        {
            oldProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();            
            clicked = 1;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Old: " + oldProcesses.Count());

        Process[] newProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
        Console.WriteLine("New: " + newProcesses.Count());

        var Difference = newProcesses.Except(oldProcesses).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("Diff: " + Difference.Count());


        string allproc = "";
        foreach(Process theprocess in oldProcesses)
        {
            allproc += theprocess.ProcessName.ToString() +"\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(allproc);

        allproc = "";
        foreach (Process theprocess in newProcesses)
        {
            allproc += theprocess.ProcessName.ToString() + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(allproc);


        allproc = "";
        foreach (Process theprocess in Difference)
        {
            allproc += theprocess.ProcessName.ToString() + "\n";
        }
        MessageBox.Show(allproc);


        /*Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
        string ProcList = "";
        string temp;
        foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
        {
            temp = theprocess.ProcessName.ToString() + "\n";
            ProcList += temp;
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: I don't think Process implements IEquatable does it? Your .Except is probably just doing a reference equals on the two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ProcessDiff : IEqualityComparer<Process>
{

    public IEnumerable<Process> GetDiff(IEnumerable<Process> oldProcesses, IEnumerable<Process> newProcesses )
    {
        return newProcesses.Except(oldProcesses, this);
    }
    public bool Equals(Process x, Process y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.ProcessName == y.ProcessName && x.SessionId == y.SessionId;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Process obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return obj.Id;
    }
}
```

And Usage:

```
        var oldProc = Process.GetProcesses();
        var newProc = Process.GetProcesses();

        var diff = new ProcessDiff().GetDiff(oldProc, newProc);
```

You actually don't need to make a separate class for this if you don't want to. You could also just make the form implement `IEqualityComparer<Process>` and add the required `Equals()` / `GetHashCode()` methods to it.  The `Except` method has a parameter for the class instance that contains the comparison method (`this` if it's called in the same class containing the `IEqualityComparer` methods).

Updated:
I added some additional constraints because `Process.Id` can be recycled. You may want to check for other factors depending on what your needs are here.  Keep in mind that an `Idle` process will throw exceptions on certain properties.

Comment: Thank you!
It is working as expected.
Would this be inefficient to use every 5-10 seconds ?
I am developing an anticheat application for a game, so with this I would check newly opened programs and check their exe md5 to compare to a database of forbidden programs.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you consider efficient.  My measure of that is usually how it impacts the user experience and processes it has to co-exist with.  Is this part of the game itself, or does it run outside of it?

Comment: It runs as a standalone application, it is basically a launcher (it starts the game which is another exe).

Comment: Since "equality" needed to be defined for the Process object, that implies that `GetProcesses()` is emitting a unique array of value objects each time it's called.  When those go out of scope, they'll be eligible for garbage collection. In most games, you tend to want to keep those GC events out of your main loop because it can impact user experience. Since it's a stand alone, I'd say it's most likely going to be fine. But you'll have to test that in the use case itself to know if it's acceptable.

Comment: Also.. if you're using the code I provided, you don't need to create a new instance of ProcessDiff every time you check.  You can make that a static member instance somewhere so that the object is created only once for the life of the application.  Then you just call the GetDiff() method off of that static object instance.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are really helpful.
I would send you some beers if I could!
Thank you for your time.